# Java with CMake and Eclipse

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, cmake

I am trying to use CMake for a Java project on Windows.
Generating a Makefile project it already fails with:

> The C compiler "C:/cygwin/bin/cc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

Why does it need the C compiler at all? Do I have to change the default programming language of CMake (if this is even possible)?

Is there a better way than generating a Makefile based project for Eclipse? For example if I want to use "add_test" in CMake. Does Eclipse recognize this as Unit Tests?

Comment: A strange and bizarre idea. Why don't you use ant or maven?

Comment: Because we widely use CMake in my company which is in my own opinion a quite useful build tool. If the Java support is good enough why should I use something else?

Comment: I am not aware the CMake has any dedicated support for build java application, am i missing something here? And while `make` and its brethren are good for building C/C++ programs, they dont work very well for java, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

According to `project` command documentation (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/project.html):

> Optionally you can specify which languages your project supports.
>   Example languages are C, CXX (i.e. C++), Fortran, etc. By default C
>   and CXX are enabled if no language options are given. Specify language
>   NONE, or use the LANGUAGES keyword and list no languages, to skip
>   enabling any languages.

So try to use `LANGUAGES NONE` in the `project` command:

```
project(project LANGUAGES NONE)
```